# Ubuntu can't mount windows share

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mount, shared-folders

I want to access by termin a Windows share so on my Ubuntu 14.04 system I executed the following command:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=dana //192.168.1.4/Users  /mnt/
```

After entering the sudo password and the windwos user password I got these error

> mount error(13): Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual
>   page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your account has permissions to mount. Use `smbclient` to try to access the drive - the smbclient command will give much more meaningful error messages why you cannot mount.

For example:

```
smbclient \\machinename\foldername -U [username] [password]
```

If it works, you will get an smb prompt like:

```
smb>
```

If not, you will get an error, such as NT_LOGON_FAILUIRE (password wrong) or if the login works but you do not have access on that folder, it will give you that error (which I can't recall off the top of my head)

Check here for info on smbclient and smbclient syntax:
[Mounting Windows Shares On Linux Using Samba/CIFS/SMBFS](http://geekswing.com/geek/linux/mounting-windows-shares-on-linux-using-sambacifssmbfs/)

Answer (score 0):

[mount(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

```
Return Codes
mount has the following return codes (the bits can be ORed):
0: success
1: incorrect invocation or permissions
2: system error (out of memory, cannot fork, no more loop devices)
4: internal mount bug
8: user interrupt
16: problems writing or locking /etc/mtab
32: mount failure
64: some mount succeeded
```

This suggest that you have generated 3 errors:

1. user interrupt
2. internal mount bug
3. incorrect invocation or permissions

Answer (score 0):

First thing always check if user has access to share and not only permissions to folder also use domain option and use -v to check debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

use this for mounting Windows share to your local Linux machine:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.your.windows.machine.hostname/Your_Share /home/user/shares/hostname/ -o vers=3.0,username=user,domain=hostname,uid=1000
```

Hope it's help.